# Mysql query is returning empty array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to have three drop downs of countries, states, and cities and I want to populate them from a database. I am successful in retrieving values for the countries drop down but the problem is the state drop down where values are shown according to selected country. As an example, if I select U.S.A I only want to get states in the U.S.
I have 2 tables `countries` and `states` and I have `country_id` as foreign key in `state` table actually this what my problem is.

My code - controller:

```
// call to fill the second dropdown with the states 
public function buildDropStates()  
{  
      // set selected country id from POST  
      echo $id_country = $this->input->post('country_id');  
      // var_dump($id_country);
      // run the query for the cities we specified earlier  
      $districtData['districtDrop']=$this->Country_states_cities->getCityByCountry($id_country);  
      // var_dump($districtData);
      $output = null;  

      foreach ($districtData['districtDrop'] as $row)  
      {  
         // here we build a dropdown item line for each  query result  
         $output .= "<option value='".$row->state_id."'>".$row->state_name."</option>";  
      }  

      echo $output;  
      // var_dump($output);
}
```

My model

```
       //fill your state dropdown depending on the selected country  
       public function getCityByCountry($country_id=string)  
       {  
            $this->db->select('state_id,state_name');  
            $this->db->from('nm_state');  
            $this->db->where('country_id',$country_id);  
            $query = $this->db->get();  
            //var_dump($query);
            var_dump($query->result());
            return $query->result();   
       }  
    }
```

and this is the view:

```
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {  
                 $("#country").change(function(){  
                 /*dropdown post *///  
                 $.ajax({  
                    url:"<?php echo  
                    base_url();?>Country_state/buildDropStates",  
                    data: {id:  
                       $(this).val()},  
                    type: "POST",  
                    success:function(data){  
                    $("#state").html(data);  
                 }  
              });  
           });  
        });   
        </script>
                <label for="country">Country</label>
                     <?php echo form_dropdown('country',$countryDrop,'','class="required" id="country" '); ?>
                     <br />
                     <br />
                    
                    
                    <label for="state">State</label>
                     <select name="state" id="state">  
                         <option value="">Select</option>  
                      </select>
```

The problem is that my model getCityByCountry() is returning an empty array with a size of 0.

When I comment the following line out of my model it returns all the values from DB so what is actually happening here? Is the foreign key Constraint not working or is it something else??

```
$this->db->where('country_id',$country_id);
```

on echoing query

```
CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 3c688b6bbc30d36af3ac34fdd4b7b5b787fe5555 $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 2 [host_info] => localhost via TCP/IP [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.6.24 [server_version] => 50624 [stat] => Uptime: 2694 Threads: 1 Questions: 6365 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 88 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 81 Queries per second avg: 2.362 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 715 [warning_count] => 0 ) [result_id] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => )
```

Comment: if I understand your question clearly... if you select a country on a dropdown the other dropdown will display all states on that country? correct?

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' yes but problem is query for returning states as in my model returns empty array[result of var_dump($query->result());]

Comment: you can use `Ajax.Post`.. create an event which is `onchange`.. then do a `select` query based on the value selected....

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' ya that also be the alternative but problem for now is why my query returning empty array

Comment: should there be an `execute()` code somewhere else?

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' i didn't get you ??

Comment: try echoing your `query` then copy paste the result of the echo and run it on your database.... just do some debugging!.

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' i tried debugging and echoing query but results are hurting my eyes i update it

Comment: `$country_id=string` this is a typo.  You should not be echoing markup from your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MODEL**

```
function get_all_where($table, $condition,$order_by=array())
{
    if(!empty($order_by))
    {
        $this->db->order_by($order_by['field'], $order_by['type']);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get_where($table, $condition);


    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$result= $this->classModel->get_all_where('nm_state', array('country_id' => $country_id));
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are echo-ing the $id_country, and the function getCityByCountry does not get the parameter therefore returning no result, remove the echo

```
  //set selected country id from POST  
  $id_country = $this->input->post('country_id');  
  //var_dump($id_country);
  //run the query for the cities we specified earlier  
          $districtData['districtDrop']=$this->Country_states_cities->getCityByCountry($id_country);
```