# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\wamp\www\news13102020\admin\process.php on line 55

Tags: php, mysqli

I write this script in roder to verify if the sql empty or not:

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])){
 $id = $_GET['edit'];
$update = true;
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id_task=$id") or die($mysqli->error());
$count = count($result);
if($count == 1){
   $row = $result->fetch_array();
   $nom_task = $row['name_task'];
   $id_operation = $row['id_operation'];
   $nom_operation = $row['name_operation'];
}
```

any suggetions to resove this please? the problem is in $count and $result?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli::query` returns a `mysqli_result` object (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
That object is not countable (meaning it cannot be used as a parameter in the `count` function)

If you want to know the number of rows returned by your SQL request, use `$num_rows` property from that `mysqli_result` object :

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT ...');
$count = $result->num_rows;
```

Also as a (very important) side note, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, please see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/601524

Comment: [If you give it a bit of a thought, you never need any counting at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64535888/285587)

Answer (score -2):

Hey try this code snippet:

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])){
 $id = $_GET['edit'];
$update = true;
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id_task=$id") or die($mysqli->error());

if(!empty($result) && count($result) == 1){
   $row = $result->fetch_array();
   $nom_task = $row['name_task'];
   $id_operation = $row['id_operation'];
   $nom_operation = $row['name_operation'];
}
```

Simply check the array if it's empty or not before count check.

Comment: $result will never be empty

Comment: Well, I think they can be check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322359/mysql-query-is-returning-empty-array

Comment: Nope they cannot. It is very important to understand the question you are trying to answer, or a post you are referring to.